# Remove Blackout Dates from WPF Calendar Blackout Date Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, date, calendar

So I wanted to Blackout all dates from 2000 from present in the WPF Calendar that aren't in a Datetime list.

My thought was to blackout all dates individually from 2000 to now and then remove each date from the blackout Date Collection.

This Code adds dates fine but it doesn't work to remove the dates from the collection.

```
var DateList = FI.Select(x => x.LastWriteTime.Date).Distinct().ToList();

for (var day = new DateTime(2000,1,1); day.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
{                
      Calendar.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(day));
}
foreach (DateTime k in Datelist)
{
    Calendar.BlackoutDates.Remove(new CalendarDateRange(k));
}
```

I compared the date range from the blackout date collection and the newly created one from the current iteration of the list but it says they aren't equivalent.

[Comparison seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDu85.png)

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`CalendarDateRange` class lets you specify a start date and end date for the range, you don't have to add a `CalendarDateRange` for every day.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendardaterange(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, there are a lot of code examples on the `Calendar.BlackoutDates` documentation :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.blackoutdates(v=vs.110).aspx

```
        var DateList = FI.Select(x => x.LastWriteTime.Date).Distinct().ToList();

        //Add all dates between DateTime.MinValue and the day before your DateList min value.
        Calendar.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateList.Min().AddDays(-1)));
```

** EDIT **

After reading your comment, it seems that I've misunderstood your issue. You're trying to remove a new instance of `CalendarDateRange`, which is different than the `CalendarDateRange` instance that was added to the collection, even though they have the same `start` and `end` values.

Replace your `foreach` block with this one to fix your issue :

```
            foreach (var k in DateList)
        {
            while (Calendar.BlackoutDates.Any(bd => bd.Start.Date == k.Date))
            {
                Calendar.BlackoutDates.Remove(Calendar.BlackoutDates.FirstOrDefault(bd => bd.Start.Date == k.Date));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I need to blackout any dates that are not in the DateList not just the ones before the start of the DateList. Also the Dates in the DateList aren't necessarily one after another, they will be in chronological order but I don't know what gaps are in the list of days that I want to Blackout.